# Symfony 5 blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, symfony, cors

I'm working on a REST API with Symfony and React.js. **Authentication works perfectly fine**, and I can retrieve user information. However, when attempting to fetch data, I encounter the following error:

> Access to fetch at 'myapi/users' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

this is how I make my request with js:

```
const fetchData = () => {
  fetch(`${apiKey}/users`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "X-AUTH-TOKEN": jwtToken,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
};
```

This is my nelmio_cors.yaml file:

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: false
        allow_origin:  ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Accept','Authorization','Cache-Control','Content-Type','DNT','If-Modified-Since',
        'Keep-Alive','Origin','User-Agent','X-Requested-With','X-AUTH-TOKEN']
        expose_headers: ['Link', 'Authorization', 'X-AUTH-TOKEN']
        max_age: 3600
        allow_credentials: true
        skip_same_as_origin: true
    paths:
        '^/': 
            allow_credentials: true
            origin_regex: true
            allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
            allow_headers: ['*']
            allow_methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
```

And this is my .env file:
`CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=.`

Comment: If you're still seeing CORS errors then check what the output of `allow_origin:  ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']` is.

Comment: Make sure to set origin_regex: true for both cases